# simple question about standard c++ multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, detach

hi i am newbie learning c++ multithreading
this ques may look stupid but just curious why it's happening
would be amazing if somebody points out what is going on underhood

so,

```
class background_task
{
public:
    void operator()() const
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
            std::cout << "Hello world " << i << std::endl;
    }
};

void Func()
{
    for(int i=0; i<1000;++i)
    std::cout << "Hello world " <<i<< std::endl;
};

void main()
{
    background_task bt;
    std::thread t(bt);

    //t.detach();
}
```

it gives me the runtime error saying "abort() has been called"
and with detach() it works just fine.
the either case, the new thread execute the loop all the way to end(1000times)
i just guess the error happens because there's additional thread going when runtime thread exits.
but even when i called detach(), there's still additional thread as well and output no error in this case.

i guess, in the destructor of std::thread, it checked like `assert(!joinable())` or am i missing something else?

Comment: Are you using a good C++ to learn about how to handle a complex topic as C++ multithreading?  If you did, what did the book say about the `thread::join` function?  Multithreaded programming cannot be looked on the same as writing regular single-threaded programs, which is probably why you're surprised at the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either detach or join `std::thread` objects before they get destroyed. This is part of the API and [documented in the destructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/%7Ethread):

> std::thread::~thread
> Destroys the thread object.
>
> If *this has an associated thread (joinable() == true), **std::terminate() is called.**

What you usually want is to join the thread, which blocks the current thread until the other thread has finished.

If you want a thread that automatically joins on destruction, you can use [C++20's std::jthread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/jthread) instead.